# How the contact form label bootstrap tooltip popup onhover message position can be modified?

Tags: template-override, joomla-3.5, bootstrap, contact-form

I am building a website, and I would like to modify the CSS position for this floating box message that is displayed when the mouse pointer is hovered over a  form field label.

How can it be achieved? What is the file that I have to edit (override)?

[image]

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website

Comment: It depends on your template. Usually you would do this with CSS override. Can you post a link to the page.